# Delete time data labels with zero value from a bar chart?

Tags: formatting, date-time, timestamp, label, pivot-chart

I am looking to remove data labels with a time format h:mm with a value of zero automatically from my pivot bar chart. Is there any way I could do this?

Here the example Pivot bar chart displaying 0:00

[image: ->Pivot bar chart displaying 0:00]

Any help is appreciated